# How many even three digit numbers are there such that the sum of the tens and units digits is 10?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many even three digit numbers are there such that the sum of the tens and units digits is 10?

I'm wondering can this be solved with using stars and bars? I have a three digit number $abc$ where $1 \le a \le 9$, $0 \le b\le 9$ and $c \in \{0,2,4,8\}$ and the condition is that $$b+c=10$$

Isn't the number of solutions to this integer equation $11 \choose 1$? So I would have $11$ possbile choices for $b,c$ and $9$ for $a$. It would conclude $99$ possible combinations.

How can I now take in consideration the eveness here?

Comment: if $c=0$, how many possibilities are for $b$?

Comment: $c=0$ is meaningless because it would yield $b=10$. So there is exactly $4$ choice for the couple $(b,c)$. Then for $a$ all choices are possible therefore in total you have $9\times 4=36$ possibilities. I'm sure there is a meaningless way to state that problem as stars and bars but it probably won't help in any kind of way.

Comment: Why isn't 6 in the set of possible $c$ values?

Comment: You do **not** want to use Stars and Bars here.

Answer (score 1):

Let $h, t, u$ be, respectively, the hundreds, tens, and units digits.  The restriction that the sum of the tens and units digits is $10$ means that
$$t + u = 10 \tag{1}$$
We are told that the number is even, so $u$ is an even digit.  Hence $t = 10 - u$ is also an even digit.

Observe that if $u = 0$, then $t = 10$, which is impossible. Similarly, if $t = 0$, then $u = 10$, which is also impossible.  Hence, equation 1 is an equation in the positive integers.

Since $t$ and $u$ are both positive even integers, we can let $t = 2t'$ and let $u = 2u'$, where $t'$ and $u'$ are positive integers.  Substituting $2t'$ for $t$ and $2u'$ for $u$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
2t' + 2u' & = 10\\
t' + u' & = 5 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the positive integers.  Thus, equation 2 has
$$\binom{5 - 1}{2 - 1} = \binom{4}{1}$$
solutions, namely $(1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)$, which correspond to the solutions $(2, 8), (4, 6), (6, 4), (8, 2)$ of ordered pairs of even integers of equation 1.

For each of the four ordered pairs $(t, u)$ of even digits that satisfy $t + u = 10$, we can select $h$ in $9$ ways.  Hence, there are $9 \cdot 4 = 36$ even three-digit positive integers such that the sum of the tens and units digits is $10$ and $2 \cdot 36 = 72$ three-digit integers such that the sum of the tens and units digits is $10$. That said, I suspect the author of the problem intended for number to be interpreted as positive integer.